# How to include URL in textual data when using Pythons lxml text() argument

Tags: html, python-3.x, xpath, lxml

I'm trying to parse some HTML data I've gathered, using the lxml library. For the most part I've had successful results extracting the values I need, however it would appear that my code does not extract URLS which are amongst textual data. The below code is just one example of a particular value where I'm having difficulty. Some of the values appear to be just text, where others are hrefs. Is there an alternative to the text() argument so that it includes the text from the URL?

```
import lxml
import json
from lxml import etree
from lxml.html.clean import Cleaner
try:
    from StringIO import StringIO
except ImportError:
    from io import StringIO

    with open('items.json') as data_file:    
    html = json.load(data_file)
    html_parser = lxml.etree.HTMLParser()

    for entry in html:
        url = str(entry.get('url', ''))
        field = str(entry.get('field1', ''))

        html_parsed = lxml.etree.parse(StringIO(field), html_parser)
        for table in html_parsed.xpath('//td/table'):
            for row in table.xpath('.//tr'):
                value = (row.xpath('.//td/text()'))
                    if "Homepage :" in value:
                        print(url)
                        print(value)
```

Examples of results so far:

Sample HTML data:

```
<td align="right">Homepage :</td><td align="left"><a href="http://www.example.com" target="_blank">www.example.com</a></td>
```

Result returned:

```
['Homepage :']
```

Sample HTML data:

```
<td align="right">Homepage :</td><td align="left">http://workingexample.com/</td>
```

Result returned:

```
['Homepage :', 'http://workingexample.com/']
```

A solution so that I can get the data I need as per the second example would be much appreciated :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly the td that you are checking for the text "Homepage" doesn't contain the URL you are after, so you can only use it to verify that you are in the correct row (more on why this is a problem later).

Secondly, the href is an attribute of a tag.  The `text()` of the tag is just the visible content on screen, this can be anything.
If you want to get the URL you need to access the attribute of the tag, the easiest way is as follows:

```
if "Homepage :" in value:
    url = row.xpath('.//td/a/@href')
```

The `@` indicates that `href` is an attribute of the `a` not a child.  So this will return the href of an `a` tag within a `td`.

The first problem may now be an issue if you have multiple `a` tags within that row, I'm not an expert in xpath, but I think the following should work (this replaces the `value = (row.xpath('.//td/text()'))`):

```
.//td[text()[contains(.,'Homepage')]]/following-sibling::td[1]/a/@href
```

If I'm not mistaken it should find a `td` that has `Homepage` in the text contents, then finds the first (`[1]`) following `td` with an `a` and grabs the `href` attribute from it.